# Can we automate both web and mobile applications using Robot Framework to perform parallel execution

Tags: java, selenium, automation, robotframework, appium-android

Can anyone tell me, can we do the parallel execution of both,web and mobile application using the robot framework? if so, how it is possible?

if we added both web and mobile application libraries, how does robot framework know which is which, i mean, how does it make a distinction between the two? Or do we have to tell it by passing a parameter or something which type of application we want it to work on?

Comment: "web and mobile application". I think this might be difficult as you would be using two different libraries. Selenium and Appium. I've used SauceLabs to have multiple executions (10) running at the same time. But even when doing iOS and Android tests where both use Appium i ended up have separate tests due to slight differences in how they react to appium.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at *Pabot*, it's a useful library which may help you doing parallel robotFramework testing.

https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot